# Conditionals inside document

Tags: conditionals

Sorry I was not able to reproduce this problem outside Friggeri's CV template...

I am using [Friggeri's CV template](https://github.com/afriggeri/cv) with the same friggeri-cv.cls (I have only changed all the Helvetica fonts to Arial). I want to use the "print" option that removes colors making everything grayscale.

With that purpose I want to include some conditionals inside the document. While I have successfully used the following structure in the preamble:

```
 \ifdefined\@cv@print 
 do this
 \else
 do that
 \fi
```

I cannot make it work inside the body of my document... is it even possible? I am new with conditionals, so I am quite lost here...

I have included the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[print]{friggeri-cv}%"BLACK&WHITE" should appear
%- or -%
%\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}%"COLORS" should appear in red

\begin{document}
\header{name}{surname}
       {occupation}

% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{section}
    aaa
    bbb
\end{aside}


\section{section}
\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {2014}
    {\ifdefined\@cv@print
    BLACK\&WHITE
    \else
    {\addfontfeature{Color=red}COLOR}
    \fi}
    {more here}
    {and more text}
\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\ifcsname @cv@print\endcsname` instead of `\ifdefined\@cv@print`, because `@` is not a letter in the document body.

Comment: Great! Thanks @egreg!! Really useful to know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\@cv@print` is not available as a command name unless you have a `\makeatletter` declaration somewhere.

Either you say

```
\ifcsname @cv@print\endcsname
```

instead of

```
\ifdefined\@cv@print
```

or, better, you define in the preamble

```
\newif\ifdaniceeprint % starts out false
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\@cv@print
  \daniceeprint
\fi
\makeatother
```

and use `\ifdaniceeprint` instead of the conditional involving `\@cv@print`.

Even better, say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printconditional}{%
  \ifdefined\@cv@print
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
 \makeatother
```

in the preamble and use

```
\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {2014}
    {\printconditional{BLACK\&WHITE}{{\addfontfeature{Color=red}COLOR}}}
    {more here}
    {and more text}
\end{entrylist}
```

in the document body.